# require_once includes some but not all files

Tags: php, zend-framework, vbulletin

Hi I have been trying to fix this problem on an old vbulletin for 3 months. I should say I only know vbscript so I find php is way over my head with all the proper programming logic! I looked for answers to my problem and the closest is sort of discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374029/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-yes-there-is).

the complete error:

**Warning: require_once(./SiteEx.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \includes\init.php on line 573**

> (SiteEx.php does exist in the same folder as other includes but for
>   some reason can't see/process it!)

**Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required './SiteEx.php' (include_path='.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library') in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\decode\includes\init.php on line 573**

> So what I don't understand is why all other require_once include files
>   with the same path run fine on lines 300, 400 etc except these.
>
> I'm running this on win 2008 r2 in Apache using Zend Community Server
>   5.10, I have restarted php, set permissions on the files etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is your casing corret? Linux filesystems are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and case is the same.

Comment: Can you post your code here, (and probably the directory structure)? It might help.

Comment: It won't let me post the code as this page is nearly 1000 lines of code :(

Comment: For example this snippet of code the first require_once is not processed yet the second one and others are. Both files exist, set permissions, filename and case correct. if (DB_QUERIES) {
  echo "<pre>";
 }

        require_once ("./includes/SiteEx.php"); //cannot see!
 require_once ("./includes/db_mysql.php");
 $DB_site = new DB_Sql_vb();
 $DB_site->appname = "Connect";
 $DB_site->appshortname = "Connect (" . VB_AREA . ")";
 $DB_site->database = $dbname;
 $DB_site->connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $usepconnect);

Comment: It was a PEAR php issue - out of date files.